# How does the input output tensors work for tensorflowjs layers api

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I have a classification problem with 8 inputs and 1 output. I create the below model:

```
const hidden = tf.layers.dense({
  units: 8,
  inputShape: [58, 8, 8],
  activation: 'sigmoid'
});
const output = tf.layers.dense({
  units: 1,
  activation: 'softmax'
});

var model = tf.sequential({
  layers: [
  hidden,
  output
  ]
});
```

Now when I predict

```
const prediction = model.predict(inputTensor);
prediction.print();
```

I expect there to be 1 output value from this prediction, but I get more, how does this work?

These are the shapes

```
console.log(input.shape) // [1, 58, 8, 8]
console.log(prediction.shape) // [1, 58, 8, 1]
```

Output looks like this:

```
   [[[[0.8124214],
       [0.8544047],
       [0.6427221],
       [0.5753598],
       [0.5      ],
       [0.5      ],
       [0.5      ],
       [0.5      ]],

      [[0.7638108],
       [0.642349 ],
       [0.5315424],
       [0.6282103],
       [0.5      ],
       [0.5      ],
       [0.5      ],
       [0.5      ]],
      ... 58 of these
```

Comment: Could give us `inputTensor.shape` and `prediction.shape`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input.shape` [1, 58, 8, 8],  corresponds to the following:

- 1 is the batch size. [More](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network) on batchsize
- 58, 8, 8 is the inputShape specified in the entry of the network

Likewise the `output.shape` [1, 58, 8, 8], corresponds to the following:

- 1 is still the batch size
- 58, 8 match the inner dimensions of the inputShape
- 1 is the last units of the network value.

If only the units values are expected, ie a layer of shape [1, 1], one can remove the inner dimensions by using `tf.layers.flatten()`.

```js
const model = tf.sequential();

model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 4, inputShape: [58, 8, 8]}));
model.add(tf.layers.flatten())
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1}));
model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});
model.fit(tf.randomNormal([1, 58, 8, 8]), tf.randomNormal([1, 1]))
model.predict(tf.randomNormal([1, 58, 8, 8])).print()

// Inspect the inferred shape of the model's output, which equals
// `[null, 1]`. The 1st dimension is the undetermined batch dimension; the
// 2nd is the output size of the model's last layer.
console.log(JSON.stringify(model.outputs[0].shape));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.1.2/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```